# не передается POST запрос

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

Добрый день друзья. Не могу разобраться есть форма в модальном окне `

```
<div class="ui mini modal">
            <i class="close icon"></i>
            <div class="center aligned header">Введите логин и пароль</div>
            <div class="content">
                <form method="post" action="index.php" autocomplete="on" class="ui form centred-form">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Пользователь:</label>
                        <input type="text" autofocus='autofocus' id="user" required='required' placeholder="Пользователь">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>Пароль:</label>
                        <input type="password" required='required' id="password" placeholder="Пароль">
                    </div>            
                </form>    
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="answer"></div>
                <button class="ui blue button" name="do_login" id="logon_button" type="submit">Войти</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

есть скрипт который следит за нажатием кнопки в форме и отправляет POST запрос на страничку index.php

```
    $("#logon_button").click(function() {

    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    $.post(
        "index.php", {
            user: user,
            password: password
        },
        onAjaxSuccess
    );

    function onAjaxSuccess(data) {

        if (data == "400") {
            $(".answer").html("Неверный логин или пароль");
        }else if(data == "200"){
            location.href = 'pages/admin.php';
        }
    }
});
```

В свою очередь index.php проверяет("должна проверять") этот запрос и авторизовать пользователя

```
    if (isset($_POST['user'])) {

    $user = R::findOne("users", "login = ?", array($_POST['user']));

    if ($user) {

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)){
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user->login;
            echo "200";

        }else{
            echo "400"; 
        }

    }
}
```

после проверки пользователя в БД index.php отправляет код 200 - все ок, и javascript должен переадресовать пользователя на страницу админ панели. Но запрос почему-то не отрабатывает, подскажите в чем проблема! Заранее спасибо!
Весь код можно посмотреть здесь https://github.com/Vankalif/pbook

Comment: добавьте `console.log(data)` и посмотрите, что вам возвращается

Comment: @rjhdby, массив и страница, хотя должен вернуться код 200 или 400`pbook.loc
array(2) {
  ["user"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["password"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Телефонная книга</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/semantic/dist/semantic.css">
`

Comment: так, массив появлялся из-за var_dump(), а тк ответом возвращается страница целиком.

Comment: Ну и еще. Если приводите ссылку на код, то хотя бы поддерживайте его в актуальном состоянии. На гитхабе у вас в `admin.php` только одна строка `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: да, так есть там ничего нет, просто я должен был увидеть php info. Так же хочу отметить, что при вводе правильного пароля я получил код 200 и всю страницу целиком. При вводе неверного логина или пароля кода 400 нет.

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что сложно ответить на вопрос "почему не работает код?" не видя кода?

Comment: Код 400 получил тоже, у меня просто нет проверки, на введенный логин. Вопрос следующий - как мне получить только код, без всего кода страницы? Либо же коды ошибок усадить в какой то элемент на странице, и javascript'ом его доставать?

Comment: Просто не нужно запихивать несвязный функционал в один скрипт. Сделайте `login.php` который будет выполнять только одно действие - проверять данные и возвращать нужный код. А для `admin.php` оставь тот функционал, который там нужен. Сейчас вы пытаетесь скрестить ужа с ежом, т.е. UI с API - это плохая практика